# Mac's sudo not sanitize PATH from user's setting?

Tags: mac, environment-variables, path, sudo

Mac's `sudo` behaviour is unlike everywhere else, of which just like observed in [Passing PATH through sudo](https://superuser.com/questions/98686/passing-path-through-sudo), sudo would flush PATH every time.

However, I found in Mac, my PATH setting is carried into sudo, which is causing  me trouble. Take a look:

```sh
$ sudo /bin/sh -x /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
++ id -u
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ rc=0
++ sudo -u nobody mktemp -t updatedb
mktemp: too few X's in template ‘updatedb’
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

+ export FCODES=
+ FCODES=
+ chown nobody
chown: missing operand after ‘nobody’
. . .

$ type mktemp
mktemp is /opt/local/libexec/gnubin/mktemp
```

What's happening is that, I've put GNU tools in PATH before the native ones, for myself only, but that setting get leaked into sudo and the different behaviour of GNU's `mktemp` breaks the Mac's native `locate` script.

Can anyone confirm, and
what's the fix please?